# iOS 11 simulator problems with private CA

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, ios11, xcode9

I am running a Tomcat server to develop and test a native iOS app. The server is presenting a certificate signed with a private CA. This is Apple's recommendation for test servers rather than using self-signed certificates. I have tested the certificate at sslshopper.com and it shows that the certificate has a CA chain. The root CA certificate has been installed on the simulator.

Initially, without any ATS exceptions, my app gives me the following:

[image: SSL error 1]

The error is the usual:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

This error is usually the result when the app encounters a self-signed certificate. As I said above, the certificate is not self-signed.

After adding an exception domain to the app's plist, I get this:

[image: SSL error 2]

This is usually what we see for certificates with an invalid CN. I have verified that the CN is correct in the certificate.

The error is :

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

I couldn't find the error in the Apple docs and finally had to resort to looking it up in the header file. It is as follows:

```
errSSLNoRootCert            = -9813,    /* cert chain not verified by root */
```

Since the chain is present and the root certificate is installed on the simulator, I'm not sure what this error means. I did notice when installing the root certificate that it would not be usable until it was enabled in the Certificate Trust Settings, but the only live content on that pane in the simulator is a link to the Apple developers site. I went to my test site in Safari and was able to access it after confirming the certificate exception. The root certificate profile says that it is verified (green checkmark).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in the iOS certificate manager. The root certificate did not have a CN, which is optional. The CN in the root is not used for any part of the verification function. The lack of the CN was confusing the cert manager and it didn't display it in the certificate management panel. One of the Apple Developer SMEs has filed a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to browse the link within the internal network if you are using internal CA certificate/Private certificate. Anyone browsing from external network he should have the root and the intermediate certificate installed on his/her browser

Also, different browsers and operating system have different procedures. For example, Chrome takes the trust store of the operating system (with the exception of EV certificates) as seen on the [Root CA Policy](http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy) of chromium.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @rodriquesf53. As I mentioned, this a native iOS application. There is no browser involved.

Comment: @SteveB, See the application is also bounded to an URL which is hosted on the server, so you need to ensure that the certificate installed on the server is matched with the URL.

Comment: I addressed that in "I have verified that the CN is correct in the certificate." The DNS name and the CN are the same.

Comment: Can you just confirm that the root certificate is installed? Root certificate is a self signed certificate

Comment: @rodriquesf53, please see the solution below.